# Display bottom shadow on fixed header and top shadow on fixed footer only visible on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, transition, css-position

I have looked on a solution that works quite well for a fixed header displaying a shadow with transition only on scroll.

Is there a way to also insert a similar fixed footer with changes to the CSS and JQuery?
The other request is if there is also a way to stop the shadow and transition when you stop scrolling midway?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz4R9/4/) is the link to that JSFIDDLE page and this script was used.

```
$(function(){

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    var opacity = $(document).scrollTop();
    opacity = (opacity > 100 ? 100 : opacity) / 100;

    $('#fixedtop').css('box-shadow', '0 5px 15px rgba(188, 0, 80, ' + opacity + ')');
});

});
```